# A conjecture about a subset of integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers, additive-combinatorics

Fix a positive integer $m$ and put
$$A_m:= \{ \sum_{k=m+1}^n k: n \ge m\}=\{\frac{1}{2}n^2+\frac{1}{2}n-\frac{1}{2}m^2-\frac{1}{2}m: n \ge m\}=
\{\frac{1}{2}(n-m)(n-m+1): n \ge m\}
$$
It is not difficult to show that $(A_m-A_m)+\{0,1,\cdots,m \} = \Bbb{Z}$  and $(A_m-A_m)\cap (\{0,1,\cdots,m \}-\{0,1,\cdots,m \})=\{0\}$ 
(because $A_m-A_m = \Bbb{Z} \setminus \{ \pm 1,\cdots,\pm m \}$).

Now, **is it true that if $B\subseteq \Bbb{Z}$ has the properties** $(A_m-A_m)+B= \Bbb{Z}$ and $(A_m-A_m)\cap (B-B)=\{0\}$, then **$|B|=m+1$** (i.e., every subset $B$ satisfying the conditions is as size as $\{0,1,\cdots,m \}$).

Note that $A-A=\{a_1-a_2: a_1,a_2\in A\}$.

Comment: Can you define the addition of sets? Do you mean union, or do you mean the addition of elements (just like for subtraction)?

Comment: Sure, $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$.

Comment: So why wouldn't $ A_m - A_m + \{ 2m\}$ work?

Comment: Where is $B$ here?

Comment: $B = \{ 2m\}$. $B-B = \{0\}$. $A_m - A_m$ contains $\{-3m, -3m+1, \ldots -m\}$, so $A_m - A_m + \{2m\}$ contains $\{ \pm 1, \ldots \pm m\}$.

Comment: The second property $(A_m-A_m)\cap(B-B)=\{0\}$ forces $B$ to be contained in an interval of length $m$; therefore, subject to this property, $|B|=m+1$ is equivalent to $B$ being an interval of the form $[b,b+m]$, correct?

Comment: @CalvinLin: if $B$ is a singleton, then $A_m-A_m+B$ is a translate of $A_m-A_m$; since $A_m-A_m$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb Z$, so is $A_m-A_m+B$. That is the first property is violated, agreed?

Comment: Ah yes. Forgot about that. Your comment should yield a correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true: writing for brevity $D=A_m-A_m=\mathbb Z\setminus\{\pm1,\dotsc,\pm m\}$, if $D+B=\mathbb Z$ and $D\cap(B-B)=\{0\}$, then $|B|=m+1$; moreover, in this case $B$ is a block of consecutive integers of length $m$.

To see this, notice first that the condition $D\cap(B-B)=\{0\}$ implies $\max B-\min B\le m$; that is, $B$ is contained in an interval of length $m$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $\min B=0$, and then $0\in B\subseteq[0,m]$. Indeed, for each $k\in[1,m]$ we must have $k\in B$, since $k\in[0,m]\setminus B$ is easily seen to imply $k\notin D+B$ (the sets $-D$ and $B-k$ are disjoint showing that $0\notin D+B-k$, whence $k\notin D+B$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why does   the condition $D\cap(B-B)=\{0\}$ imply $\max B-\min B\le m$ (we only know that $(B-B)\setminus \{0\}\subseteq \{ \pm 1,\cdots,\pm m \}$ thus $\max (B-B)-\min (B-B)\leq 2m$ ).

Comment: @M.H.Hooshmand: because $D\cap(B-B)=\{0\}$ shows that the difference of *any* two distinct elements of $B$ (and in particular, the difference of $\max B$ and $\min B$) is not in $D$; that is, the difference belongs to the complement of $D$ in $\mathbb Z$, which is the set $\{\pm1,\pm2,\dotsc,\pm m\}$.

Comment: Right, an interesting solution, thanks.